# Watching order for Dreamland and The Infinite Quest in Doctor Who

Tags: doctor-who

This is more of a request for advice, since I think there probably is no canon answer. If I was to watch a Doctor Who marathon, and include the animated episodes Dreamland and The Infinite Quest, what would be a good place to put them in the episode order?

Comment: I'd suggest watching Dreamland after The Doctor's Daughter, because of Georgia Moffet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### [Infinite Quest:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Infinite_Quest)

> As Martha is traveling freely with the Doctor, **the story may be set
>   somewhere between the series three episodes "42" (which follows
>   directly on from Martha's invitation to long-term travel in "The
>   Lazarus Experiment") and "Utopia" (which begins the series finale).**
>   However, the Character Bios on the DVD release state that Martha is
>   traveling with the Doctor for one more trip, which seems to set it
>   before "The Lazarus Experiment". <sub><sup>Wikipedia</sup></sub>

### [Dreamland](http://www.digitalspy.co.uk/tv/s7/doctor-who/tubetalk/a189375/phil-ford-talks-dreamland-waters-of-mars.html#~oNmwjKY1e97oOS)

In an interview with DigitalSpy, Phil Ford (the show's writer) has categorically stated that Dreamland takes place immediately following the special episode "Water of Mars":

> **Where does it fit in the Doctor's timeline?**
>
> ***"It's set after 'Waters of Mars'. It's a much more light-hearted story than 'Waters of Mars' or the story that will follow it.*** As I
>   think Russell said elsewhere, just because of the dark ending of
>   'Waters of Mars' it doesn't necessarily mean the rest of the journey
>   is going to be doom-laden. The Doctor stops off for a bowl of chili -
>   the kind of chili you could only get in an American diner before 1962,
>   as he says!"